# Lispworks 7.0 load zeromq fail in Windows 10

Tags: common-lisp, zeromq, lispworks

I use the **LispWorks7.0** to load the **zeromq** on my PC with windows 10, and got the error message as below:

```
    CL-USER 13 > (ql:quickload :zeromq)
To load "zeromq":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    zeromq
; Loading "zeromq"
; gcc -o C:\Users\chaoqi\AppData\Local\common-lisp\cache\lw-7.0.0-win-x64\g\third_codes\quicklisp\dists\quicklisp\software\cl-zmq-20160318-git\src\grovel__grovel-tmpXOBV8AQ3.obj -c -m64 -Ig:\third_codes\quicklisp\dists\quicklisp\software\cffi_0.19.0\ C:\Users\chaoqi\AppData\Local\common-lisp\cache\lw-7.0.0-win-x64\g\third_codes\quicklisp\dists\quicklisp\software\cl-zmq-20160318-git\src\grovel__grovel.c

Error: Subprocess run with command ("gcc" "-o" "C:\\Users\\chaoqi\\AppData\\Local\\common-lisp\\cache\\lw-7.0.0-win-x64\\g\\third_codes\\quicklisp\\dists\\quicklisp\\software\\cl-zmq-20160318-git\\src\\grovel__grovel-tmpXOBV8AQ3.obj" "-c" "-m64" "-Ig:\\third_codes\\quicklisp\\dists\\quicklisp\\software\\cffi_0.19.0\\" "C:\\Users\\chaoqi\\AppData\\Local\\common-lisp\\cache\\lw-7.0.0-win-x64\\g\\third_codes\\quicklisp\\dists\\quicklisp\\software\\cl-zmq-20160318-git\\src\\grovel__grovel.c") exited with error code 1
  1 (continue) Retry PROCESS-OP on #<CFFI-GROVEL:GROVEL-FILE "zeromq" "src" "grovel">.
  2 Continue, treating PROCESS-OP on #<CFFI-GROVEL:GROVEL-FILE "zeromq" "src" "grovel"> as having been successful.
  3 Retry ASDF operation.
  4 Retry ASDF operation after resetting the configuration.
  5 (abort) Give up on "zeromq"
  6 Return to level 0.
  7 Return to top loop level 0.

Type :b for backtrace or :c <option number> to proceed.
Type :bug-form "<subject>" for a bug report template or :? for other options.

CL-USER 14 : 1 >
```

I'm sure that, I use my Vistual Studio 2015 and compiled the **x64 version** **libzmq.dll** and set the cffi path ok.
Because I use the ccl with lispbox install the zeromq and work fine, the output message as below:

```
CL-USER> (ql:quickload :zeromq)
To load "zeromq":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    zeromq
; Loading "zeromq"

(:ZEROMQ)
CL-USER>
```

I want to known, why error message with gcc stuff and how to fix this.
As I know, it just loads the dll where the **cffi:*foreign-library-directories*** pointed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Two things: **A**) Do you have a positive evidence that any trivial example of a ZeroMQ code loads and works inside your IDE tool-chain? **B**) Have you tried so far to ask the LispWorks Support / Knowledge base for this and similar exceptions - with what responses?

Comment: @user3666197 I send the E-mail and got no responses, maybe there need some more time to wait

Comment: @user3666197 I use the Vistual Studio 2015 write some example with the generated x64 version dll and lib and works fine.